# Anomalydetection's Non existing by clause

Tags: splunk

The Search Command, [Anomalydetection](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Anomalydetection), does not have a by clause but I want to be able to group the data via a field, and run the Anomaly detection on each grouping separately.

Is there a way todo this in a contained report with out resorting to multiple reports/searches, one for each grouping.